# Disable new keyboard shortcut for Show Desktop

Tags: unity, 14.04, compiz, dconf, show-desktop

After a recent upgrade of 14.04, an icon "Show Desktop" appeared in my launcher bar.

I removed it with Unity Tweak Tool.

A new keyboard shortcut was also setup: `Super+D` now also shows the desktop. This is annoying, since pressing `Super+Alt+D` in that order is not the same as pressing `Alt+Super+D` in that order. The former is erroneously interpreted as `Super+D` on my machine.

What I would like to do in a first step is to disable `Super+D`, but I cannot find where I can turn this off.

Here are the things I checked:

- nothing in **Settings > Keyboard**
- there is something in **CompizConfig Settings Manager > Unity > General**, but it is set to `<Control><Super>d`. Disabling it does not disable `<Super>d`.
- I disabled the shortcut in **Unity Tweak Tool > Window Manager > Keyboard shortcuts > Show desktop**
- gconf-editor -> apps/compiz-1/plugins/showdesktop, I can't find anything about keyboard shortcut there
- dconf-editor -> org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell -> show-desktop-key is Disabled

How do I disable the new `<Super>d` shortcut?

Comment: By default here super+d does nothing. However if the show desktop icon is added to the launcher then it's enabled. To disable super+d try - in System Settings > Appearance > Behavior disable the Add show... box or if already then enable then disable. Then log out/in & check.

Comment: In terminal run `dconf -reset /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/show-desktop`

Answer (score 1):

As hinted by @doug in the comments, I needed to log out and in for the change to apply.

Removing the "Show Desktop" icon worked immediately, which is why I expected the shortcut to also be removed immediately. It was not.

It is still very strange that the shortcut was active, but not visible in any of the settings tools I mentioned in the question. It looks like the shortcut was hard-coded together with the icon enable/disable. Why the icon turned up at my last system update is also a mystery.

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts can be overriden via "Keyboard and shortcuts" item in control panel